# ERROR ITMS-90644: "Missing Image Asset Xcode 8.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, imageicon, imessage-extension, uiimageasset

Please refer the error below.

> ERROR ITMS-90644: "Missing Image Asset. Your app is missing the Large App Icon asset 'Messages Icon' in 'Payload/StickerU.app/PlugIns/MessageExtension.appex'."

Checked all thing 9 times but every time fail to upload to App Store.

Comment: Did you check all App iCON set by you in image assets >> app icons ?

Comment: Post the content of file `/path/to/StickerU/MessagesExtension/Assets.xcassets/iMessage App Icon.stickersiconset/Contents.json`.

Comment: i had checked all the things. i had already uploaded more then 10 stickers apps to App Store successfully ,but this time i am uploading App and Extension both and i m stuck here.

Comment: Extension not supporting image editor framework(may be other frameworks also not support) , and in result it was giving me this kind of error.I removed that framework and all good without change in icon in Assets.

Answer (score 0):

You may have not add iMessage supported image (with size  1024x768) in your image asset. Add all missing images/icons in your app (related to iMessage, if you've added support iMessage)

See, for more details: [Uploading app with iMessage stickers.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52920)

- Remove an emtpy Sticker Sequence in the assets, if you've any.
- Common suggestion: Use latest Application Loader to upload your app on app store

Comment: I am using all required size of icons. no success, I had check MessageExtension.appex content and there is no file after making .ipa file